# Use the default attribute title in a b-form-input in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I've been trying to make some validation on my input in a vuejs app and after some research I realized that maybe vuejs doesn't support title.

Here's the snipper of my code :

```
<b-form-input size="sm" required pattern=".{2,}" title="Entrez au moins 2 characteres" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" id="recherche" name="recherche" placeholder="Rechercher"/>
```

The problematic part is that both the required and the pattern works but the title is still the default one ("The field is required") instead of the one I want.

I would like to use the default validation of html, so did anyone had this problem ?

Comment: It's not that Vue doesn't support it, it's whatever library you are using that implemented that component doesn't. I would look over the documentation of the component and see what it *does* support.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting, I'm not a pro in vuejs, so I'll look into what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/

Scroll to "Component Reference"

You will see that component does not support the title attribute.  It isn't a VueJS problem.

You might submit a pull request to them, as this seems like a good idea.

Comment: I also assumed it was bootstrap-vue, and to be honest, given the way the component is written, I would expect it to work, given that props are copied to the root element of the component if they are not defined (which title clearly isn't). [Here is an example of it working](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzprplv7kp). I'm not sure what is going on with the OP's code.